# How can I avoid uninstalling the app when compile

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, air, flashdevelop

I have a general question for about Intellij IDE
by default when I compile my air app in android or iOS devices , this IDE first uninstall my app and then install , but I don't want to uninstall my app !
is there any way to avoid uninstall app on device ? like flashDevelop IDE

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not possible at the moment, please [follow this issue for updates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127053).